# Obtain a package 1st version's date of publication

Tags: r, package, release, versions

Documentation of R packages only include the date of [last update/publication](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html). 
Numbering of versions do not follow a common pattern to all packages.
Therefore, it is quite difficult to know at a glance if the package is old or new. Sometimes you need to decide between two packages with similar functions and knowing the age of a package could guide the decision.

My first approach was to plot downloads per year: [By traking CRAN downloads](http://www.r-bloggers.com/finally-tracking-cran-packages-downloads/). This methods provides also the relative popularity/usage of a package. However, this requires a lot of memory and time to proceed. Therefore, I would rather have a faster way to look into the history of one package.

**Is there a quick way to know or vizualize the first version's date of release of one specific package or even to compare several pakages at once?**

The purpose is to facilitate a mental mapping of all available packages in R, especially for newcomers. Getting to know packages and managing them is probably the main challenge why people give up on R.

Comment: I wouldn't judge a package based on age. There are several very good very old r programmers floating around here.

Comment: While it is interesting that `packageDescription` doesn't have any sort of `first published`, I think you are undervaluing 1) older packages, that if they are still being talked about, stood the test of time, 2) well maintained packages. 

That is, I'd be interested in knowing the most recently *updated* packages via `packageDescription(pkg)$`Date/Publication``.

Comment: You could search the cran archives. Each package has every version with the date published. That isn't in R (at least with a quick search I haven't found a way to have R list all previous version) method. But it is pretty quick.

Comment: I am not discriminating against old packages. As  rawr and Andrew said, they stood the test of time. And sometimes that exactly what you want a very tested, and stable package. But sometimes new packages are based on newer technologies. For example ggplot2, ggplot, gvis..., while the base plot function is good, better alternative exists nowadays with a new syntax.

Comment: I feel like you'd get much more knowledge out of reading the documentation for two packages to see what is in them or reading blogs using either package, than you would simply looking at the date of first publication. I think you're proposing a poor methodology to answer an important question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and support. Of course I read the documentations, that's what I spend most of my time doing. But one piece of the puzzle was missing. How they all relate in time. The purpose is to facilitate a mental mapping of all available packages in R. But I seem to be the only one thinking this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
## not all repositories have the same archive structure!
archinfo <- function(pkgname,repos="http://www.cran.r-project.org") {
    pkg.url <- paste(contrib.url(repos),"Archive",pkgname,sep="/")
    r <- readLines(pkg.url)
    ## lame scraping code
    r2 <- gsub("<[^>]+>"," ",r)   ## drop HTML tags
    r2 <- r2[-(1:grep("Parent Directory",r2))]  ## drop header
    r2 <- r2[grep(pkgname,r2)]                  ## drop footer
    strip.white <- function(x) gsub("(^ +|  +$)","",x)
    r2 <- strip.white(gsub("&nbsp;","",r2))     ## more cleaning
    r3 <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(r2," +"))      ## pull out data frame
    data.frame(
        pkgvec=gsub(paste0("(",pkgname,"_|\\.tar\\.gz)"),"",r3[,1]),
        pkgdate=as.Date(r3[,2],format="%d-%b-%Y"),
        ## assumes English locale for month abbreviations
        size=r3[,4])
}
AERinfo <- archinfo("AER")
lme4info <- archinfo("lme4")
comb <- rbind(data.frame(pkg="AER",AERinfo),
              data.frame(pkg="lme4",lme4info))
```

We can't compare package numbers directly because everyone uses different numbering schemes ...

```
library(dplyr) ## overkill
comb2 <- comb %>% group_by(pkg) %>% mutate(numver=seq(n()))
```

If you want to arrange by package date:

```
comb2 <- arrange(comb2,pkg,pkgdate)
```

Pretty pictures ...

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(comb2,aes(x=pkgdate,y=numver,colour=pkg))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I rejected an edit to order by package date, but added a `dplyr::arrange` solution.  It's not clear to me why you need the results ordered in this way? It's relatively un-idiomatic to require a particular ordering of rows in a data frame ...

Comment: The minor addition of sorting by date makes `numver` follow the right pattern in some special cases. If you look at [ggplot2 Archive page](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/), version 0.5 comes after 0.5.7. Therefore for some packages, the plots will experience a weird spike that is only due to the way `numver` was created. Thanks again for the code and the tip on `arrange` @Ben Bolker!

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew Taylor suggested, [CRAN Archives](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/) contains all previous versions and the date is indicated.

Comment: This is an excellent way to determine the exact version of a package that was on CRAN on a specific date.